# Jquery Ajax is neither passing data to PHP nor returning anything on success()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to pass the jquery variable to PHP with Ajax but the receiving php file is returning error " Undefined index" Code is:

```
  <div class="img">
    <a href="ss.php">
       <img id="theme_bg" src="images/themes/theme1.jpg">
    </a></div>


$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.img').on('click','img',function(){
        var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        alert(imgsrc);       //this is returning the img src correctly 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ss.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {imgpath:imgsrc },
    success: function(response) {
    content.html(response);    // i tried alert here but it shows nothing
    }
});
});});
```

receiving PHP file code is:

```
 <?php
    $imagepath = $_POST['imgpath'];
    echo $imagepath;
 ?>
```

I tried it with GET also but same error.. I haven't used Ajax before this. I checked other responses here on similar questions but none of them was has anything majorly different from mine code. so dont know what's the error..

[updated Screen shots of code both files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT32Z.jpg)

[updated screen shots of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJJmT.jpg)

Comment: I did that but still it didn't return or pass anyting

Comment: 1) Check the console for errors, especially the network tab to see what the response from the request is. 2) call `stopPropagation()` on the event passed to the click handler to stop the page being redirected before the AJAX request completes

Comment: Damn you saw that one :) I neglected to notice that the click handler was running. Umm, you could try removing the `dataType` and let it default to URL encoded?

Comment: dataType: 'json', you dont need this if you are expecting string response, use try catch it may happen another code in your ss.php causing this error

Comment: i stopped the propagation, removed the json. tried checking console for errors. console is not showing any error. but its still not working..

Comment: can you update full error description & your full php code

Comment: @Omi the receiving PHP code is just only what i have mentioned in my problem. on executing it shows error Undefined index imgpath in receiving php file. That is the  $imagepath = $_POST['imgpath'];

Comment: Mr. Omi @RoryMcCrossan  I added the screen shots of both code and output. hopefully it will clear the problem.. i tried console but it didn't show anything.. if you can

Comment: Now that you've shown the error message the problem is clear - you cannot make an AJAX request to the local file system. You need to be running your code on a webserver for it to work. You can quite easily install IIS or XAMPP to do this

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i already have iis .. running all the php code on it.  i did the same with this code. m learning ajax. so may be i am not getting how to actually execute it..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I changed the ajax code to this and it starts alerting the data on source file where ajax is being fired I added new screenshots please check them once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you wrote `ss.php` in anchor you dont need that that's why it redirecting `ss.php` on click and getting error undefined index.

Your html code should be like this:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="ss.php">
    <div class="img">            
        <img id="theme_bg" src="images/themes/theme1.jpg">
        <input name="imgpath" id="imgpath" type="hidden"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.img').on('click', 'img', function () {
            var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
            $("#imgpath").val(imgsrc);       //this is returning the img src correctly 
            $("#myForm").submit();
        });
});
```

ss.php

```
 <?php
   $imagepath = $_POST['imgpath'];
   echo $imagepath;
?>
```

Comment: but then it will not navigate to ss.php my program requirement is that i have to pic the src of image user clicked on img. php then use it on the ss.php.

Comment: you want to redirect in ss.php?

Comment: I tried removing <a> tag and put window.location='http://localhost/ss.php'; but still the same error:  PHP Notice:  Undefined index: imgpath in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ss.php on line 5

Comment: yes the requirement is to pick the image source  whichever image user clicked from img. php then pass it to ss. php.

Comment: it worked :):) the thing is mine is a gallery of different pictures one of which will be clicked by user and its source will be passed to the ss.php page. so putting  a gallery in a form is bit strange dont you think?

Comment: at a time you click on only one image na so it wont matter

Comment: You can keep your code outside of <form></form> if you want just keep hidden input their inside form no matter , it ll work fine with gallary

Comment: Okkzz.. great .. thank you so much for your help :):):) i was stuck here since last week. thanks a lot. :):)

Answer (score 1):

You have dataType set to json

so PHP should php `<?php echo json_encode([$imagepath])`

The better solution would be dataType: text instead of JSON

Note that in $.ajax  the dataType is for response not request

Check $.ajax manual http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i removed it as it was not required but still no result

Comment: you should keep it not remove it , with it removed jQuery will guess the type depending on header content-type, in that case you'll have to set it using PHP header("Content-type: text/plain"); so it's easier to keep it but set it correct

Comment: i changed its type to text

Comment: do you still have issues when it's type is text ? if so please check your browser console to see if there is any javascript errors

Comment: no with some other additions it start showing the ajax response but the second php page is not getting the value sent by the ajax. i have uploaded the screen shots in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Add this one to document.ready function

> ```
> $(".img").click(function() {
>   $.ajax({
>     type: "POST",
>     url: "ss.php",
>     data: {imgpath:imgsrc},
>     dataType: "text",
>     cache:false,
>     success:
>         function(data){
>           alert(data);
>         }
>   });// you have missed this bracket
>   return false;
> });
> ```